# How to create an email workflow in classic sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, classic-experience

I have made my workflows for a classic list using sharepoint designer 2010 which got deprecated now. How can I create new workflows in my classic sharepoint list now.

Comment: You can still create SP 2013 workflows for classic lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SharePoint 2013 workflows for classic sharepoint list.

For SharePoint 2013 workflows, the retirement doesn't apply to SharePoint 2013 workflows. SharePoint 2013 workflows will remain supported, but will be retired at some point in the future.

Here's PowerShell to enable SharePoint 2013 workflows for tenant.

```
Set-SPOTenant -StopNew2013Workflows $TRUE
```

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.